# If two of the $13$ members of a computer programming team refuse to work together, how many groups of seven can be chosen to work on a project?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How is this calculated? I know a possible way to calculate it would be to find the total number of combinations and subtract the number of combinations with only the two people in the group. None of the solutions I found are convincing. Please help!

Comment: What you have to subtract is the number of groups of seven that include both of those team members.

Answer (score 1):

The number of groups of $7$ where the two members in question work together is $\binom{11}{5}$. (This is the number of ways to choose 5 of the remaining 11 team members to work together with the two problematic team members, forming a group of 7.) Thus the number of acceptable groups of $7$ is $\binom{13}{7} - \binom{11}{5}$.

Comment: But, aren't we subtracting a group of seven people with a group of five people? Is it even allowed?

Comment: Do you know what the notation $\binom{a}{b}$ is?

Comment: @Vaskar To form an inadmissible group of 7, we can start with the two people who don't like each other, then select 5 more people to join their group. This gives us a group of 7 people (including the two enemies).

Comment: I believe that it's "b"-combinations that can be chosen from set of "a" elements. But, yeah I don't think I understand it quite well.

Comment: @Vaskar Another way of writing the answer is $\binom{13}{7} - \binom{2}{2}\binom{11}{5}$, where $\binom{13}{7}$ is the number of ways of selecting $7$ of the $13$ team members and $\binom{2}{2}\binom{11}{5}$ is the number of ways we could take both of the people who refuse to work together and five of the other computer programming team members.

Answer (score 0):

The total number of ways to choose the seven member is $\binom{13}{7}$. Let's count the combinations that we DON'T want, namely, that the two people are working together. If the two people are on the project, there are another 5 people needed to be chosen from the remaining 11 people, or $\binom{11}{5}$. So your answer is these two combinations subtracted from the other.

Comment: Thanks for responding. But, how can we take out a group of five people from a group of seven people? That's the thing driving me crazy.

Comment: Okay, let's take it one step at a time. Do you understand the reasoning behind the total number of ways to choose the seven members?

Answer (score 0):

*But, how can we take out a group of five people from a group of seven people? That's the thing driving me crazy.*

I read your words as: You interpreted the symbol $\Large{11\choose 5}$ as: the result is a group of five people. This is wrong, as @N. F. Taussig pointed out in the comment that is a shorthand of

$${2\choose2}\cdot{11\choose5}=1\cdot{11\choose5}={11\choose5},$$

you should find that the first in the above has two numbers added up to $7$. When solving a combinatorics problem I would recommend you first write down each step you're doing clearly, e.g. the steps for the above is:

$$\textrm{(choose the two who fight into a group)}\cdot\textrm{(choose the other five people to join them)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**  A direct count.

A group formed without the two team members who refuse to work together must contain neither of them or exactly one of them.

*Neither of the two team members who refuse to work together is selected*: Then seven of the remaining $13 - 2 = 11$ team members must be selected, which can be done in 
$$\binom{2}{0}\binom{11}{7}$$
ways.

*Exactly one of the two team members who refuse to work together is selected*:  We must select one of the two team members who refuse to work together and six of the remaining eleven team members, which can be done in 
$$\binom{2}{1}\binom{11}{6}$$
ways.

*Total*:  Since the two cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the number of ways a group of seven team members can be selected if two of the team members refuse to work together is 
$$\binom{2}{0}\binom{11}{7} + \binom{2}{1}\binom{11}{6}$$

**Method 2:** An indirect count.

There are $$\binom{13}{7}$$ ways to select a group of seven of the thirteen team members.  From these, we must subtract those selections that include both of the team members who refuse to work together.

If both team members who refuse to work together were selected, we would also have to select five of the other team members to complete the group, which can be done in 
$$\binom{2}{2}\binom{11}{5}$$
ways.

Hence, the number of ways seven team members can be selected for the project if two of the team members refuse to work together is 
$$\binom{13}{7} - \binom{2}{2}\binom{11}{5}$$